# Persistent volumes with docker-compose and RStudio/Jupyter

Tags: r, docker, jupyter-notebook, rstudio, volume

I am trying to create an *RStudio instance* and a *Jupyter Notebook instance* using docker-compose building an image. I can create these instances but the volumes mounted do not seem to be "persistent".

Below is the tree structure of my folders:

```
.
├── Docker
│   ├── docker-compose.yml
│   └── Dockerfile
└── R_and_Jupyter_scripts
    └── files_already_there.txt
```

I would like:

1) The `files_already_there.txt` to be available in my RStudio and Jupyter Notebook instance.

2) That any new file/script created from one of the two instances appears in the `R_and_Jupyter_scripts` folder with read/write permissions. **i.e**: I created a textfile *"output.txt"* from the RStudio instance but when I check the path, here is where the file is saved:

```
sudo find / -name "output.txt"
/var/lib/docker/overlay2/821d3d087948309e3c489af29a5263e53e5f72627e903b4285a9597214412840/diff/home/maxence/output.txt
/var/lib/docker/overlay2/821d3d087948309e3c489af29a5263e53e5f72627e903b4285a9597214412840/merged/home/maxence/output.txt
```

Below is my current docker-compose.yml, can you identify what is wrong?

```
version: "3.5"
services:
  rstudio:
    environment:
      - USER=maxence
      - PASSWORD=password
    image: "rocker/tidyverse:latest"
    build:
     context: ./
     dockerfile: Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - /home/ec2-user/R_and_Jupyter_scripts:/var/lib/docker/
    container_name: rstudio
    ports:
     - 8787:8787

  jupyter:
    image: 'jupyter/datascience-notebook:latest'
    ports:
     - 8888:8888
    volumes:
      - /home/ec2-user/R_and_Jupyter_scripts:/var/lib/docker/
    container_name: jupyter
```

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have your Dockerfile and it looks like you're running an Amazon instance, so I can't reproduce this for certain but if I delete the Dockerfile part and make some other edits I can make something that works on my Ubuntu 18 machine.

```
version: "3.5"
services:
  rstudio:
    environment:
      - USER=maxence
      - PASSWORD=password
    image: "rocker/tidyverse:latest"
    volumes:
      - /tmp/R_and_Jupyter_scripts:/home/maxence/R_and_Jupyter_scripts
    container_name: rstudio
    ports:
      - 8787:8787

  jupyter:
    image: 'jupyter/datascience-notebook:latest'
    ports:
      - 8888:8888
    volumes:
      - /tmp/R_and_Jupyter_scripts:/home/jovyan/R_and_Jupyter_scripts
    working_dir: /home/jovyan/R_and_Jupyter_scripts
    container_name: jupyter
```

I used `/tmp/R_and_Jupyter_scripts` as the location outside the containers.

In Rstudio, `/home/maxence` is created because this corresponds to the `USER` that is specified and this will be the location that is shown when you log in. I then simply created a directory below this in the `volume` directive to be the location of the files outside the containers. When you log on to Rstudio, you will see a folder called `R_and_Jupyter_scripts` that you will be able to enter and create whatever you like (I thought `working_dir` would work but it always seems always to start in the home folder)

In the Jupyter image you are using, the default user is `jovyan` so a folder `/home/jovyan` will be created automatically. I then use this in the `volume` and `working_dir` directives. The Jupyter container will use this `working_dir` when you log on.

I tested it and read and write works in all 3 places.

Using `/var/lib/docker` will create a volume correctly inside each container, the issue is that there is no way for either client to be able to set their location to it.

Comment: Thanks a lot  Andrew ! I changed the `tmp` folder for a folder in my `ec2-user` folder and it is working perfectly fine :)